# How can I use flume to split the data in the body into different channels?

Tags: java, hadoop, flume

I would like to use a flume agent and split the data of the body according to a defined function and send one part of the body data into one sink and the other part into the other sink.

Do I need to implement a custom interceptor for that or are there default solutions that I missed reading the Flume User guide?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You have to write a custom interceptor.

You could use Interceptor's intercept method and split body of each event based on your function. later you can assign a meaningful header to that specific part of body that can be used as redirection or channel selector parameter for flume fan out flow.

Once you have your code ready you could add following properties in you flume `conf` file and implement Multiplexing -

Mapping for multiplexing selector:

```
Agent.sources.Source1.selector.type = multiplexing

Agent.sources.Source1.selector.header = someHeader
Agent.sources.Source1.selector.mapping.Value = Channel1
Agent.sources.Source1.selector.mapping.Value2 = Channel1 Channel2
Agent.sources.Source1.selector.mapping.Value3 = Channel2
```